# css - use !important

Tags: css

```
case 1
    <body>
        <div id="main1">
            <div class="myClass">
                <h3 class="heading"> Text Text </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

case 2
    <body>
        <div id="main2">
            <div class="myClass">
                <h3 class="heading"> Text Text </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

case 3
    <body>
        <div id="main3">
            <div class="myClass">
                <h3 class="heading"> Text Text </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <style>
        #main1 h3{
            font-size: 20px;
            margin:10px;
            padding:20px;
        }

        #main2 h3{
            font-size: 6px;
            margin:15px;
            padding:50px;
        }

        #main3 h3{
            font-size: 23px;
            margin:30px;
            padding:10px;
        }
        div.myClass h3.heading{
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            font-size:10px;
        }
    </style>
```

myClass seems like a module and will be input somewhere like , case 1, case 2, case 3 .. case n

So that h3 will have another style follow the each of case style

How i can use only style `div.myClass h3.heading` ?

Note:

- only edit HTML in div myClass , not parent
- h3 only use CLASS , not ID, not inline style

  - don't add #main div.myClass h3.heading because i don't know parent of myClass .It maybe #main1 #main2 or #something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Real answer after even more clarification**:

- You can't edit the HTML of the parent of `<div class="myClass">`.
- You don't know what the `id` of that parent will start with.

I give up. Your situation is *ridiculous*.

Use inline styles or add an `id` to your `h3` as suggested by @Guffa, or use `!important` on every rule:

```
div.myClass h3.heading {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

---

**Real answer after clarification:**

In your comment, you said you have:

```
#main1 #main2 ,.. #main n
```

Due to this fact, you should add a `class` to each `div`, like this:

```
<div id="main1" class="main">
..
<div id="main2" class="main">
..
<div id="main3" class="main">
```

Then you can use this:

```
.main h3 {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:30px;
    padding:10px;
}
div.myClass h3.heading {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

Or if you **REALLY** can't add a `class` for some reason:

```
<div id="main1">
..
<div id="main2">
..
<div id="main3">
```

along with:

```
div[id^="main"] h3 {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:30px;
    padding:10px;
}
div.myClass h3.heading {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-size:10px;
}
```

That's using the CSS3 attribute-starts-with selector to find all `div`s that have an `id` starting with `main`. It's better than doing this:

```
#main1 h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px;
}
#main2 h3 {
    font-size: 6px;
    margin:15px;
    padding:50px;
}
#main3 h3 {
    font-size: 23px;
    margin:30px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

---

**Old answer:**

You should use this selector:

```
#main .myClass h3.heading
```

Note that I changed `myclass` to `myClass` - *nothing* was going to work until that change was made. `class`es are case-sensitive.

To learn how to solve these types of problem yourself, you should learn about *specificity*:

- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

---

[image]

`#main h3` has a specificity of `0,1,0,1`.

`div.myClass h3.heading` has a specificity of `0,0,2,2`.

It's all about the number on the left.

Because you have a `1` in that second column for `#main h3` due to the `id` (`#main`), you really need to use an `id` if you want to override it, as in my answer:

`#main .myClass h3.heading` has a specificity of `0,1,2,1`.

Comment: Yes, for leftwards to make CSS selectors more specific. See: http://blogs.sitepoint.com/get-specific-css-styles/

Comment: Hmm after the code formatting edit, I see you said `Not use .. #main`. I'll look again.

Comment: yeah , not add #main , because #main can be change to something #main1 #main2 ,.. #main n ..

Comment: thank for suggestion , but css3 with IE :(( haven't permission to edit HTML of myClass's parent, only edit HTML of myClass and child of myClass

Comment: Can you use my second suggestion, under the sentence "`Or if you REALLY can't add a class`"?

Comment: div[id^="main"] will work all browser ? :-s , if use important ? how to use ?

Comment: `div[id^="main"]` will work in every modern browser. The sole browser it won't work in that [you *might* care about](http://ie6countdown.com/) is IE6. It *will work* in IE7/IE8/IE9.

Comment: yeah , but i forget that i don't know id of parent , it can be main , or something :-s

Comment: I am thinking about SASS ! Any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

> Not use !important or add #main

You have to make the style more specific than the one you want to override. The only possibilities if those two are ruled out, is to either use an id on the element:

```
<h3 id="heading"> Text Text </h3>

div.myClass #heading {
```

or to set the style inline:

```
<h3 class="heading" style="margin:0;padding:0;font-size:10px;"> Text Text </h3>
```

Comment: h3 will be repeat more time , so don't use ID . and say NO with inline :(

Comment: @Chameron: Then you would need a separate id for each one. If you can't change the surronding code or the style for that code, then those are your only alternatives. To override a selector with an id without using !important, you need another selector with an id, or inline styles.

Comment: so i have to write important over times :-s

Comment: @Chameron: Yes, if you can't add an id to the header, then you are limited to using inline styles or !important.

Answer (score -1):

jsut add `!important` after `div.myclass h3.heading` `font-size`

```
div.myclass h3.heading
{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        font-size:10px !important;
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue @Chameron is running into. He's not defining the right class because of a typo.